# Table of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a table of dicts looking like:

```
[{
    'variant_id': 4126274, 
    'stock': [
        {'stock_id': 6, 'quantity': 86}, 
        {'stock_id': 4, 'quantity': 23}, 
        {'stock_id': 3, 'quantity': 9}
    ]
}, ...]
```

My goal is to unzip every piece of stock to look like this:

```
[{'variant_id': 4126274, 'stock_id': 6, 'quantity':86}
{'variant_id': 4126274, 'stock_id': 4, 'quantity':23}
{'variant_id': 4126274, 'stock_id': 3, 'quantity':9}...]
```

Is there any fast and optimal way to do this?

Comment: Maybe take a look at [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)?

Comment: @RafaeldeBem The result is a list, not a dictionary, so a list comprehension is needed.

Comment: actually the result is a list of modified dictionaries, so a dictionary comprehension could very well help here...

Comment: @RafaeldeBem I can't find a way to use a dictionary comprehension for this solution. It's a list comprehension that contains a dictionary as its "value" (see my answer, which does that thing)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```py
result = [{'variant_id': entry['variant_id'],
    'stock_id': stock_entry['stock_id'],
    'quantity': stock_entry['quantity']} for entry in table for stock_entry in entry['stock']]
```

This gives

```
[{'quantity': 86, 'stock_id': 6, 'variant_id': 4126274},
 {'quantity': 23, 'stock_id': 4, 'variant_id': 4126274},
 {'quantity': 9, 'stock_id': 3, 'variant_id': 4126274}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches: one with nested for loops, and one with a list comprehension.

```py
data = [{'variant_id': 4126274, 'stock': [{'stock_id': 6, 'quantity': 86}, {'stock_id': 4, 'quantity': 23}, {'stock_id': 3, 'quantity': 9}]}]

result = []

for entry in data:
    for stock in entry['stock']:
        result.append({'variant_id': entry['variant_id'], 'stock_id': stock['stock_id'], 'quantity': stock['quantity']}) 
print(result)

result_list_comprehension = [{'variant_id': entry['variant_id'], 'stock_id': stock['stock_id'], 'quantity': stock['quantity']} for entry in data for stock in entry['stock']]
print(result_list_comprehension)
```